# Java - Which accounting module is best to embed in my JAVA application?

Tags: java, module, accounting

I am developing a java application. I want to integrated some accounting module in my app. I don't want any feature-rich accounting module. I just want to maintain

- salaries
- expenses
- generating invoices

So do you know any **FREE OPEN SOURCE** accounting module so that I can integrate it with my app.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at GNU i think it meets your description:

> http://www.gnuaccounting.org/